# Github for Mac not showing diffs on code sources

Tags: git, github-for-mac

I've been using GitHub for Mac for about a week or so with great success.  However, after the auto-update to version 1.2.8, github will no longer show the diffs for me on a .m file:

[image]

It will seem to compare other files, though, for example, a .pbxproj file:

[image]

I have an inkling that somewhere whatever decides can and cannot be compared accidentally got switched to think that .m and .h files aren't comparable.

Comment: I have the same issue, hopefully the next update will fix this nasty bug.

Comment: Me too. I emailed GitHub tech support yesterday, but no response yet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed as of Github for Mac 1.2.10.  Please update your clients.